# « Laissez-passer » signifie-t-il « mot de passe » chez Maupassant ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Dans la nouvelle [« Deux Amis »](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/46470/46470-h/46470-h.htm#ch_15) de Maupassant, publiée en 1883, les personnages éponymes franchissent un poste militaire. On les laisse passer, ce sur quoi

> Ils se remirent en marche, munis d'un laissez-passer.

Plus tard, un ennemi leur demande un « mot d'ordre » qui lui permettrait de franchir ce poste. Ils refusent de répondre (ils se taisent et ne révèlent rien à l'ennemi) et sont fusillés.

Pour moi, un *laissez-passer* est forcément un document écrit. Ce ne peut pas être synonyme d'un *mot d'ordre*, qui signifie ici un mot de passe. Les deux amis ne pouvaient donc pas révéler de *mot d'ordre* puisqu'il n'en avaient pas. Ils auraient éventuellement pu révéler leur possession du *laissez-passer*, mais ce n'était pas exactement ce que l'ennemi demandait.

Un traducteur vers l'anglais n'est pas d'accord avec moi : [il ou elle a traduit *laissez-passer* par *password*](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/123/in-two-friends-why-does-the-colonel-allow-the-two-men-to-go-into-a-warzone).

Est-ce que les mots *laissez-passer* et *mot d'ordre* peuvent être synonymes, compte-tenu du contexte et de l'époque ? Ou désignent-ils forcément, comme dans mon idiolecte, l'un un document écrit et l'autre un secret ?

Comment: *Le Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* confirme ce que tu dis sur laissez-passer, c'est un document. Par contre j'ai trouvé [une autre traduction en ligne](http://bclearningnetwork.com/LOR/media/EN12/Resources/Two_Friends.pdf) où *laissez-passer* est traduit par "*pass*" et "*mot-d'ordre*" par "password", ce que je trouve correct.

Comment: That translation is clearly a mistake. A laisser-pass in English on a military base etc. is a pass.

Answer (score 3):

Je n'avais pas pensé à consulter Littré, qui est presque contemporain de Maupassant, et qui ne donne aussi que le sens de document écrit pour [*laissez-passer*](http://www.littre.org/definition/laissez-passer), et d'un mot de passe pour [*mot d'ordre*](http://www.littre.org/definition/mot#var18). Il ne peut donc s'agir de la même chose.

Comment: Case closed, je dirais.

Comment: @Tunedéroberas - "ordre" n'est pas forcément oral ou écrit. Je peux concevoir un ordre écrit aussi bien que verbal. Un "mot" peut également être écrit aussi bien que verbal. Est-ce que cela répond à votre question?

Answer (score 3):

Je partage ton avis. Traduire « laissez-passer » (écrit) par « mot de passe » (parlé) est un contresens et modifie substantiellement le récit.

Étant tous sous autorité militaire, les militaires et les espions  susceptibles de traverser les avant-postes connaissent forcément le mot de passe (= mot d'ordre).

Les civils ne peuvent et ne doivent eux pas le connaître car ils ne sont pas sous les ordres des militaires. Ils sont en revanche susceptibles de bénéficier d'un laissez-passer nominatif délivré par la plus haute autorité militaire du lieu.

Les prussiens pensent que les deux protagonistes sont des espions, et connaissent donc le mot de passe.
Ils exigent qu'il leur soit divulgué mais c'est bien sûr impossible :

- Conclusion, les deux amis meurent « bêtement », fusillés suite à leur « fantaisie » (inconséquence causée par la faim et peut-être aussi à la consommation d'absinthe) mais surtout à « l'erreur judiciaire » qui s'ensuit. Le colonel n'a pas mis l'armée en danger.

D'après la traduction, le colonel leur a donné ce mot de passe (« *password* »). Dans ce cas :

- Les deux amis meurent en héros, refusant la haute trahison. Le colonel a mis l'armée en danger.

Cette dernière interprétation est tout à fait inconcevable, particulièrement s'appliquant à une zone de guerre.

Comment: It’s not clear if the friends still had the pass, but it seems they'd've kept it until they re-crossed the check point. If that’s true, I think it’s a bit harsh to deny that it was heroic of them to not reveal their pass to try to prove that they weren't spies (as you said, spies would know the password & wouldn’t need a written pass). Even if they felt they’d be killed anyway (which is likely, imo, even if they had known & revealed the true password), I think their silence & resulting deaths stem more from their heroic/patriotic desire to not reveal anything to the enemy than from stupidity.

Comment: @PapaPoule They have nothing to reveal and the pass has not much value. It is only valid for the two of them. The Prussian officer is unable to believe their explanation (whether explicit or implicit) so has no doubt they know the password. A real password is a very sensitive piece of information and might have allowed spies or whoever to cross the front line toward the French side. Maupassant is not describing an heroic event but showing how war can be absurd.

Answer (score 2):

Je crois que dans ce cas, le "laissez-passer" est une lettre, ou un document écrit, que l'on peut présenter physiquement a un barrage pour pouvoir le passer. Le terme "sauf-conduit" me vient aussi a l'esprit pour la même chose.

La [neuvième édition du *Dictionnaire* de l'Académie française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/laissez-passer) donne la définition suivant:

> Titre autorisant quelqu'un à pénétrer et circuler dans un endroit déterminé. Délivrer un laissez-passer permanent. Présentez votre laissez-passer à la sentinelle.

qui à mon avis exclut la possibilité de *password* ou d'un simple *mot de passe* verbal.

Pour ce qui est de *mot d'ordre*, le même dictionnaire donne:

> Le mot d'ordre et le mot de ralliement, en termes de guerre, [sont] les deux mots qu'un chef donne à ceux qui sont sous ses ordres, pour qu'ils puissent se reconnaître entre eux. Quand un poste reconnaît une patrouille, il en reçoit le mot d'ordre et lui donne celui de ralliement.

Et pour le *sauf conduit*:

> Sorte de passeport par lequel il est permis à une personne d'aller en quelque endroit, d'y demeurer un certain temps et de s'en retourner librement, sans crainte d'être arrêtée.

Comment: Donc tu es d'accord avec moi, et pas avec le traducteur. Je me fais aussi plus confiance qu'en ce traducteur non nommé, mais peut-être sait-il quelque chose que je ne sais pas. As-tu une référence plus complète ? Par exemple un dictionnaire historique ?

Comment: Oui, je suis d'accord avec toi, et pas avec le traducteur. CRNTL contient quelques dictionnaires historiques, regardes ici: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/portail. ou ici: http://www.lexilogos.com/francais_langue_dictionnaires.htm.